# I'm not able to excute perl script inside ajax

Tags: ajax, perl, asterisk

I have set of AJAX code, that code call a Perl Script and script have some functionality.Whenever i click on Dial button Perl script should be run but i'm not able to run script.When i click on dial button my complete Perl program is showing on Web.On other had when i execute my program forcefully it executed properly.

HTML Code

```
<!CTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">


<html>
<body>

<title>Outbound Calling Demo Site</title>
<script language="Javascript">


        function doDial(phone)
                {
                var phone_no = document.getElementById('phone').value;
//              alert(phone_no);

                var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                        { //Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                        ajaxRequest= new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                        }
                else
                        {

                        try {
                                ajaxRequest= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
                            }
                        catch (e) {}
                        try { ajaxRequest= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); }
                        catch (e) {}
                        try { ajaxRequest= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
                            catch (e) {}
                        throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");

                        }
                 // Create a function that will receive data
                 // sent from the server and will update
                 // div section in the same page.

                function handler()
                        {
                        if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200)
                        {
                        document.getElementById("ajaxDiv").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
                        }
                        }




                 var queryString = "?phone=" + phone_no ;
                 get_selected_data(document.getElementById('agent'));


                if(ajaxRequest != null)
                        {
                        ajaxRequest.open("POST", "dial_call2.pl" +  queryString , true);
                        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = handler;
                        //console.log(queryObj.fund);
                        ajaxRequest.send(null);
                        }
                else
                        {
                        window.console.log("AJAX (XMLHTTP) not supported.");
                        }

                }

</script>



                 <table >
                                Number to dial: <input class="text_box" name="phone" type="text" id="phone"  size="14" value="" />
                                <input type="button" value="Dial" onClick="javascript:doDial();"/>
                                <div id='ajaxDiv'></div>

                         <tr>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf1" value='1'  id="dtmf1" onClick="sendDTMF(1);"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf2" value='2'  id="dtmf2" onClick="sendDTMF(2);"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf3" value='3'  id="dtmf3" onClick="sendDTMF(3);"/></td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>

                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf4" value='4' id="dtmf4" onClick="sendDTMF(4);"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf5" value='5' id="dtmf5" onClick="sendDTMF(5);"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf6" value='6' id="dtmf6" onClick="sendDTMF(6);"/></td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf7" value='7' id="dtmf7" onClick="sendDTMF(7);"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf8" value='8' id="dtmf8" onClick="sendDTMF(8);"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf9" value='9' id="dtmf9" onClick="sendDTMF(9);"/></td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf*" value='*' id="dtmf*" onClick="sendDTMF(this.value);"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf0" value='0' id="dtmf0" onClick="sendDTMF(0);"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmf#" value='#' id="dtmf#" onClick="sendDTMF(this.value);"/></td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmfClr" value="Clr" onClick="number_clear(this.value);"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" name="dtmfC" value="C" onClick="number_c(this.value);"/></td>
                         </tr>

                </table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <td><input type="button" id="hangup" value="Hangup" onClick="javascript:doHangup();"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" id="unregister" value="Unregister" onClick="javascript:doUnregister();"/></td>
                                <td><input type="button" id="answer" value="Answer Call" onClick="javascript:doAnswer();" style="visibility:hidden;"/><br/></td>
                            </th>
                        </tr>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Perl Code :-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI;
my $cgi = new CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use IO::Socket;

print $cgi->header();
print $cgi->start_html('Asterisk Caller');
print '<center><p>call</p>';

my ($request,@phone_no,$phone_no);
        if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "GET")
                {                                             
                $request = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};              
                }                                             
        elsif ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")
                {                                      
                    read(STDIN, $request,$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}) || die "Could not get query\n";
                }

my @phone_no=split(/=/,$request);
my $phone_no;
my $phone_number = $phone_no[1];
chomp($phone_number);

my $host = '127.0.0.1';
my $login = "Action: login\r\nUsername: lite\r\nSecret: 4003\r\n\r\n";
$/ = "\r\n";    # <> reads a single line for signon banner

#       Code for making  connection with Telnet

my $s = IO::Socket::INET->new("$host:5038") or die "can't connect to $host: $!\n";
my $banner = <$s>;      # read the banner

my $line = ('-' x 78)."\n";
print $banner,$line;

print $s $login;
my $resp = <$s>;

print $resp,$line;

print $s "Action: Originate\r\nChannel: DAHDI/42/$phone_number\r\nContext: oreilly\r\nExten: s\r\nCallerID: 7702009896\r\nPriority: 1\r\nWaitTime: 10\r\nRetryTime: 20\r\nMaxRetries: 2\r\n\r\n";

$resp = <$s>;
print $resp,$line;

print $s "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n";
$resp = <$s>;
print $resp,$line;

close $s;
```

Comment: You should take a look at this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810

Comment: That's a web server configuration issue (it's not setup to executes that file as a CGI script) or a permission issue (the file doesn't have the execute flag on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apache and running on a Linux server, then the following *may* help.

You may need the following `.htaccess` file alongside your Perl code:

```
<FilesMatch "\.pl$">
  Options +ExecCGI

  SetHandler cgi-script
</FilesMatch>
```

For this to work you'd also need to ensure that the Perl script is executable:

```
chmod 755 myscript.pl
```

.. and that the first line of the script is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```